# Elasticsearch java validate api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to validate a query before saving it for use later. I see ES has a [validate API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-validate.html) but it cant see a way to use it with the Java api.

Is there a way to validate ES queries using the java api?

Maybe I could just run the query before saving it?

Comment: > IF you use java for elastic-search, why not you use java-driver of elacticsearch and query by querybuilder : [Query Builder](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.3/query-dsl-queries.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after looking at the elastic search source code I came up with this solution.

```
public ActionFuture<ValidateQueryResponse> validateAsync(QueryBuilder query, String[] indices) {
    final ValidateQueryRequest request = new ValidateQueryRequest();
    request.indices(indices);
    request.source(query.buildAsBytes());
    return esClient.admin().indices().validateQuery(request);
}
```